# Shadow maps, reducing "shimmering"

Tags: opengl, shadow-mapping

I'm doing shadow maps, and my shadows move around, "shimmer", when I move around the camera. It is difficult to spot on still images but very much noticable in motion.

I read an MSDN article describing the very same problem - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416324(v=vs.85).aspx - but even with their fix, the problem still very much persists - in fact, I hardly see any difference at all.

Here's how I construct view/projection for my directional light source, and the measures I take to combat "shimmering" yet which does not work - why?

```
Mat4 CreateDirLightVPMatrix(const Vec3& lightDirection, const Mat4& viewProjectionMatrix, const float shadowMapResolution)
{
    const Vec3 lightDir = glm::normalize(lightDirection);
    const Vec3 perpVec1 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(lightDir, Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
    const Vec3 perpVec2 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(lightDir, perpVec1));

    Mat4 rotationMatrix(Vec4(perpVec1, 0.0f), Vec4(perpVec2, 0.0f), Vec4(lightDir, 0.0f), Vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    Vec4 corners[8] = { Vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
                        Vec4(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), Vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f) };
    const Mat4 inverseVPMatrix = glm::inverse(viewProjectionMatrix);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        corners[i] = inverseVPMatrix * corners[i];
        corners[i] /= corners[i].w;
        corners[i] = corners[i] * rotationMatrix;
    }

    float minX = corners[0].x, minY = corners[0].y, minZ = corners[0].z, maxX = corners[0].x, maxY = corners[0].y, maxZ = corners[0].z;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (corners[i].x < minX)
            minX = corners[i].x;
        if (corners[i].x > maxX)
            maxX = corners[i].x;
        if (corners[i].y < minY)
            minY = corners[i].y;
        if (corners[i].y > maxY)
            maxY = corners[i].y;
        if (corners[i].z < minZ)
            minZ = corners[i].z;
        if (corners[i].z > maxZ)
            maxZ = corners[i].z;
    }

    Mat4 viewMatrix(rotationMatrix);
    viewMatrix[3][0] = -(minX + maxX) * 0.5f;
    viewMatrix[3][1] = -(minY + maxY) * 0.5f;
    viewMatrix[3][2] = -(minZ + maxZ) * 0.5f;
    viewMatrix[0][3] = 0.0f;
    viewMatrix[1][3] = 0.0f;
    viewMatrix[2][3] = 0.0f;
    viewMatrix[3][3] = 1.0f;

    Vec3 halfExtents((maxX - minX) * 0.5, (maxY - minY) * 0.5, (maxZ - minZ) * 0.5);
    // supposed fix from MSDN article - does not have any effect at all
    float texelSize = 1.0f / shadowMapResolution;
    halfExtents.x /= texelSize;
    halfExtents.y /= texelSize;
    halfExtents = glm::floor(halfExtents);
    halfExtents.x *= texelSize;
    halfExtents.y *= texelSize;

    return glm::ortho(-halfExtents.x, halfExtents.x, -halfExtents.y, halfExtents.y, halfExtents.z, -halfExtents.y) * viewMatrix;
}
```

Comment: How about adding one or two images or a short video clip, even if it's hard to see? Depending on your actual scene, just rounding to integers might not be enough.